# An increasing function with particular properties

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm looking for a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function $g(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ of the form $\arctan(f(x))$ such that:

1. $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f(x))=+\infty$
2. $f$ is increasing (or better strictly increasing).
3. $g'(x)$ has NO limit as $x$ tends to $+\infty$.
4. $f$ is a sum, difference product and ratio and composition of elementary functions so it is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$.

For point 3) the problem is that
$$
g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{1+(f(x))^2}
$$
tends to $0$ as $x\to+\infty$
for all the example i tried to find.
I start to think such a function do not exist.